# python count variable is not updating in my main function when calling it back to the main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

what I am trying to do is I am counting the number of 1's which are neighbors of  1 in the matrix and then when I count for a certain [x][y] the I count the number of neighbors and save them in an identical matrix named matrix_qualities

Now the issue I am facing is that when the if loop recognizes the neighbors as 1 it should count the number of neighbors and then put it in the matrix but the count is not getting updated in the main when I call it back in the function for comparing the next neighbour

```
def compare(x, y, count, Matrix, rows, columns):
    while x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x <= (int(rows) - 1) and y <= (int(columns) - 1):
        if Matrix[x][y] == 1:
            count += 1
            break
        break
    return count


def main():
    String = input("Enter the example")
    _list = String.split(" ")

    print(_list)

    rows = _list[0]
    columns = _list[1]

    Matrix = [[0 for x in range(int(columns))] for y in range(int(rows))]

    z = 2

    for x in range(0, int(rows)):
        for y in range(0, int(columns)):
            Matrix[x][y] = int(_list[z])
            z += 1

    Matrix_qualityies = [[0 for x in range(int(columns))] for y in range(int(rows))]

    for x in range(0, int(rows)):
        for y in range(0, int(columns)):
            count = 0
            if Matrix[x][y] == 0:
                Matrix_qualityies[x][y] = 0
            if Matrix[x][y] == 1:
                if x >= 1:
                    compare(x - 1, y, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if x >= 1 and y >= 1:
                    compare(x - 1, y - 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if x >= 1 and y <= (int(columns) - 1):
                    compare(x - 1, y + 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if x <= (int(rows) - 1):
                    compare(x + 1, y, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if x <= (int(rows) - 1) and y >= 1:
                    compare(x + 1, y - 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if x <= (int(rows) - 1) and y <= (int(columns) - 1):
                    compare(x + 1, y + 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if y >= 1:
                    compare(x, y - 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
                if y <= (int(columns) - 1):
                    compare(x, y + 1, count, Matrix, rows, columns)
            Matrix_qualityies[x][y] = count

    print(Matrix)
    print(Matrix_qualityies)


main()
```

input is 2 9 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1

Comment: fix your indentations.

Comment: there was no problem while compiling I'll try to fix it on this page

Comment: I fixed the indentations

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of your `compare` function

Comment: thankyou soo much for reminding me that I got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably simplify your comparisons and accumulation of neighbors by extracting it to a helper function:

Something like this maybe?

```
import random

NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS = [(1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1)]


def get_moore_neighbors_sum(array_of_arrays, row, col):
    sum_neighbors = 0
    for neighbor in NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS:
        dr, dc = neighbor
        try:
            if row + dr >= 0 and col + dc >= 0:
                sum_neighbors += array_of_arrays[row+dr][col+dc]
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return sum_neighbors


rows, cols = 5, 4
mat = [[random.choice([0, 1]) for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]
mat_qualities = [[get_moore_neighbors_sum(mat, r, c) for c, _ in enumerate(row)] for r, row in enumerate(mat)] 

for row in mat:
    print(row)

print()

for row in mat_qualities:
    print(row)
```

#### example of output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]

[3, 4, 3, 2]
[5, 6, 5, 1]
[5, 6, 6, 3]
[4, 6, 5, 3]
[2, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: I am actually still in the learning phase of python so I dont really know how to use `random` or `try` and `except` but your code is much more efficient than mine as I can see 
I'm still trying to understand the try and exception block

Comment: Thankyou for the answer

Comment: random is there to generate some dummy data for testing purposes; try/except is idiomatic to python where it is often considered Easier to ask for Forgiveness than for Permission. loof here for EFAP: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

Comment: I got the error **module 'random' has no attribute 'choice'**

Comment: Are you sure that you copy/pasted correctly? `random` has a method `choice`

Comment: yeah I did 
now it says it cannot import choice from random

Comment: I'm sorry for such stupid doubts but I recently started programming in python I dont know anything about it thats why I'm asking it

Comment: It is okay, take a deep breath, and let's start again: (1) start a new interpreter, (2) copy/paste exactly what I posted, (3) run it and see that it works. Once done, you can start to modify parts and make it fit in your code, you will get there.

Comment: it worked !! 
in the spyder 
but it wasnt working when I pasted in in sublime and ran it on cmd

Comment: ok, cool, well done! - when something like this happens, it is often useful to take a step back to try to figure it out... With spyder, you need to be careful, the interpreter keeps data from previous runs alive; sometimes, before making modifications to the code, it is better to restart the interpreter to purge the data that was assigned earlier.

Comment: okay thankyou 
now I am trying to figure out how to fit my data inside your code
I saw enumerate in it I am trying to understand it